# How to populate records in a 2D string array as I do not have record count before calling sqlite3_step()?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I need to a allocate a 2D string array to return the results of the query to the caller. The query might be something like

```
   Select * from files where size > x
```

The 2D array that I need to allocated is something like

```
   std::string [x][y];
```

I know the number of columns but ofcourse I do not know how many rows will match the query. I have to allocated the memory before hand to put the result set.

I know I can execute a seperate query like, but that's an overkill and there should be no need to execute a seperate query.

```
   select count(*) from files where size > x
```

Perhaps a I can rethink a more dynamic 2D data structure to push the results ? I am not sure any ideas ?

Comment: Are you asking how to know the number of results before you fetch them? Or are you asking how to allocate space to hold an arbitrary number of results? And are you using C or C++?

Comment: C++, but sqlite is C api . answer to any question can help, either knowing row count of dynamically allocating memory for rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a `std::vector < std::vector < std::string > >` ? That one can grow dynamically and the number of rows can be easily inspected via `vector.size()`.

Depending on how you're executing your queries, sqlite does tell you the number of rows returned. For example, see here for `sqlite_get_table()`: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html . It returns the number of rows in `*pnRow`.

Comment: You are right .. I thought sqlite would provide some way to give us matching row count

Comment: sqlite_get_table() is legacy interface, not recommended as per docs, I am uisng recommendation on this page http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html